# How to use onchange to render ejs via a select element

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, ejs, onchange

I am using Node.js to render EJS files. I want a user to fill out a log form and have their data sent to a database.  The initial part of the form is in log.ejs, is rendered via log.js, and is incomplete.  When the user selects an option, I want the rest of the form to show up.  I want each option to render a slightly different form (i.e. easyForm, longrunForm, etc.) and complete the original form while still using log.ejs.  I've tried to accomplish this by adding `<%- include('logForms/easyForm.ejs') -%>` after the incomplete form in log.ejs and have tried doing this several different ways with the `<select>` elements `onclick=""` attribute.  I have not come up with functioning code and I do not know the best way to go about this with EJS format.  If I manually add `<%- include('logForms/easyForm.ejs') -%>` after the incomplete form in log.ejs, then the form loads and I can save data successfully to my database.  Any help would be appreciated.

log.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') -%>

<!--Form begins but has no closing -->
<form class="" action="/log" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="workoutDate" class="">
    <label for="">Time</label>
    <input type="time" name="timeOfDay" placeholder="Time of day hh:mm">
    <select class="" id="workoutSelect" name="workoutType" onchange="">
      <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
      <option value="run">Run</option>
      <option value="longRun">Long run</option>
      <option value="shakeout">Shakeout</option>
      <option value="workout">Workout</option>
      <option value="race">Race</option>
      <option value="xTrain">X-Train</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<!--This is where specific logForm is used to add appropriate fields and close the form -->

<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') -%>
```

log.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Data = require('../models/data');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('log');
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const data = new Data ({
      date: req.body.workoutDate,
      timeOfDay: req.body.timeOfDay,
      type: req.body.workoutType,
      otherData: req.body.otherData,
  });

  data.save()
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results);
      res.render('log');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```